# Writing a plist

Tags: objective-c, ios, file-io, plist

I am trying to test out writing a dictionary to a plist.
The following code does not report any errors, but I cannot find any trace of the file that I supposed wrote.
Here is the code snippet:

```
 NSDictionary *myDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
 @"First letter of the alphabet", @"A",
 @"Second letter of the alphabet", @"B",
 @"Third letter of the alphabet", @"C",
 nil
 ];
```

I can see the dictionary contents displayed properly with either method calls:

```
NSLog(@"Here is my partial dictionary %@", myDictionary); 

for (NSString *key in myDictionary)
    NSLog(@"here it is again %@ %@", key, [myDictionary objectForKey:key]);
```

The following code displays the "succeeded" message when the program is run repeatedly

```
if ([myDictionary writeToFile: @"myDictionary" atomically:YES ] == NO)
    NSLog(@"write to file failed");
    else
    NSLog(@"write to file succeeded");
```

even when changing the atomically: argument to NO to not write a temporary file.
However, when I search my current directory, or even my entire Mac, I cannot find any file called "myDictionary.plist" or any file with the string "myDictionary".

Isn't the path variable "@myDictionary" supposed to represent the file at the current directory, i.e. where the class executable resides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code tells the system to write the dictionary on a file, but on what file, what is the path to the file's location? Alekkhya's code does that, it defines a particular directory in the application sandbox(the Documents directory), gets the path to it and writes the file there.

I suggest you read [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072).

Comment: I don't see any declarations for paths or directories in the code that you've posted

Comment: Does't the code snippet                                                             [myDictionary writeToFile: @"myDictionary" atomically:YES ]               specify "myDictionary" as a file written to the current directory? At least that's what the reference book (for example, Kochan, p. 436) says.

Comment: I don't think so. You'd have to get the reference to the directory you want to write to. There is nothing like a current directory. Remember that your app is executing in a sandbox environment. I suggest you to read the apple doc from the link in my post.

Comment: ok, thanks. I guess the examples (even in the highly-recommended books on this site) shouldn't be taken at face value...

Comment: If an answer helps you , don't forget to click on the 'right' mark next to it(to accept it as the solution). You don't seem to be accepting answers to any of your questions.